Telegram referral system (unable to count referral count)
So I'll get straight to the point, I'm making a telegram referral bot, I made so that you can generate an invite link (unique for every user). I want to be able to track how many times each specific link was used or in other words, track referral count. At first I tried achieving this with python-telegram-bot, however, it seems Telegram Bot API have limitations, whose restrict from checking what invite link were used when new member joined.
This was my attempt:
async def on_member_join(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    result = extract_status_change(update.chat_member)
    if result is None:
        return
    
    print("Member joined!")
    # Log every event to see what's captured
    # print("Update received:", update)
    
    was_member, is_member, invite_link = result
    print(invite_link)
    cause_name = update.chat_member.from_user.mention_html()
    # print('Cause Member')
    # print(update.chat_member)
    cause_user_id = update.chat_member.from_user.id
    member_name = update.chat_member.new_chat_member.user.mention_html()
    # print('New Member')
    # print(update.chat_member)
    
    result = update.chat_member
    if result.new_chat_member.status == 'member':  # Checks if the user has just joined.
        print(f"New member joined: {result.new_chat_member.user.name}")
        # Extract the referral code from the user's status message
        # referral_code = member.status.split('start=')[1]
        if (update.chat_member.from_user.id):

            # Update invite count for the inviter using the referral code
            conn = sqlite3.connect('referral_bot.db')
            cur = conn.cursor()
            try:
                cur.execute('UPDATE users SET invite_count = invite_count + 1 WHERE user_id = ?', (cause_user_id,))
                conn.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error updating invite count: {e}")
            finally:
                conn.close()

And this is extract_status_change function:
def extract_status_change(chat_member_update: ChatMemberUpdated) -> Optional[Tuple[bool, bool]]:
    """Takes a ChatMemberUpdated instance and extracts whether the 'old_chat_member' was a member
    of the chat and whether the 'new_chat_member' is a member of the chat. Returns None, if
    the status didn't change.
    """
    status_change = chat_member_update.difference().get("status")
    invite_link = chat_member_update.invite_link
    old_is_member, new_is_member = chat_member_update.difference().get("is_member", (None, None))

    if status_change is None:
        return None

    old_status, new_status = status_change
    was_member = old_status in [
        ChatMember.MEMBER,
        ChatMember.OWNER,
        ChatMember.ADMINISTRATOR,
    ] or (old_status == ChatMember.RESTRICTED and old_is_member is True)
    is_member = new_status in [
        ChatMember.MEMBER,
        ChatMember.OWNER,
        ChatMember.ADMINISTRATOR,
    ] or (new_status == ChatMember.RESTRICTED and new_is_member is True)

    return was_member, is_member

But as I mentioned I realised that Telegrom Bot API doesn't have such capabilities, so now I'm trying to combine Client and Bot API, at first tried telethon with no success and now I'm locked on Pyrogram. I can there is a get_chat_invite_link_joiners() method. However, using this one I get error: [400 BOT_METHOD_INVALID] - The method can't be used by bots (caused by "messages.GetChatInviteImporters"). I set up Pyrogram with bot token, instead of the phone number. That being said, bot cannot use it, maybe there is some other workaround? Can I somehow make "User" bot to achieve it? I want to count referrals and store them in database, for later use. This is my attempt on Pyrogram:
@pyro_client.on_message(filters.command("referral") & filters.group)
async def create_invite(client, message):
    try:
        new_link = await client.create_chat_invite_link(message.chat.id, member_limit=1)
        await message.reply(f"New Invite Link: {new_link.invite_link}")
    except Exception as e:
        await message.reply(f"Failed to create invite link: {e}")

@pyro_client.on_message(filters.command("leaderboard") & filters.group)
async def track_invite_links(client, message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    invite_link = message.text.split(maxsplit=1)[1] if len(message.text.split()) > 1 else None

    if not invite_link:
        await message.reply("Please provide the invite link you want to track.")
        return

    try:
        response = f"Users joined with {invite_link}:\n"
        async for joiner in client.get_chat_invite_link_joiners(chat_id, invite_link):
            user = joiner.user
            response += f"- {user.first_name} {user.last_name or ''} (ID: {user.id})\n"
        # await message.reply_text(response)
        print(response)
    except Exception as e:
        # await message.reply_text(f"Failed to fetch joiners: {e}")
        print(f"Failed to fetch joiners: {e}")

I also looked into this Pyrogram's ChatInviteLink, however I cannot figure out how to use it and if the bot can even use it.
I would appreciate any help and tips on this issue, thank you in advance!

Please clarify which capabilities exactly you're missing in the Bot API. also not that the return value of extract_status_change does not match your usage of it (was_member, is_member, invite_link = result). Finally, please also have a look at the recent bot API updates https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog#may-6-2024
